# Saving Cover Pages Microsoft Word 2008 for Mac

Tags: microsoft-word

I am currently working with Microsoft Word Mac 2008 to create a 'Cover Page'.

I am able to adjust / edit an existing template from the 'Document Elements' tab, though I want to be able to edit a cover page and then save the revised art into the Document Elements tab for future use throughout the document.

I tried going through the Word application files to see if I could locate the folder which contained the Cover Page elements so see if I could manually change or add a new file, though I could not locate it. I do think it's actually part of the application.

If anyone knows how to save a cover page template into the document elements tab, It would be so great to hear / learn how to do it.